# jQuery version error with foundation

Tags: jquery, zurb-foundation

I am getting an error on button click as "elem.getattribute is not a function" if I use jQuery 2.1.4 but when I use jQuery 2.2.4 then that error automatically disappears

Comment: that would be spelled `getAttribute` - and in jQuery `.attr()`- please show some code. Visit the [help] to see how and what to ask

Comment: So use the jQuery 2.2.4 version? If `elem` is a DOM element then the method name should be `.getAttribute` and not `.getattribute`. I don't think that version of jQuery has such a basic error!

Comment: If you post your code we can see if you have an issue with for example `$(someselector).attr("someattribute","somevalue")` which should be `$(someselector).prop("someproperty","somevalue")` instead - like here: https://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-2-1-4-bug

Comment: which version of Foundation are you using